# how to use api in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, nodejs-server

I am trying to use API from here http://www.postalpincode.in/Api-Details

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const port = 3000
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html"))
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const query = req.body.cityData;  // gets the input from the form tag
    // const dataType = req.body.dataType;
    const url = `https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/586101`;
    https.get(url, (response) => {
      response.on("data", (data) => {
        const pinData = data();  // converts other format into json
       
        const place = pinData.0.PostOffice[0].Name; //<== i this line it is showing error for 0 after pinData
        res.set("Content-Type", "text/html");   
        res.send(`place:${place}
              `);
      });
    });
  });

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: is it possible that "const place = pinData.0.PostOffice[0].Name;" should be "const place = pinData[0].PostOffice[0].Name;"

maybe you could console.log pinData for us so we can see the structure of it?

Answer (score 1):

You must access the numeric keys like so:

> const place = pinData[0].PostOffice[0].Name;
> I've just double-checked on Chrome they way you tried and it will throw `VM273:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`.

I was able to get the endpoint response by just pasting the url into the browser. It looks like this after parsing.

```
[
  {
    "Message": "Number of pincode(s) found:7",
    "Status": "Success",
    "PostOffice": [
      {
        "Name": "Bijapur",
        "Description": null,
        "BranchType": "Head Post Office",
        "DeliveryStatus": "Delivery",
        "Circle": "Karnataka",
        "District": "Bijapur(KAR)",
        "Division": "Bijapur",
        "Region": "North Karnataka",
        "Block": "Bijapur",
        "State": "Karnataka",
        "Country": "India",
        "Pincode": "586101"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bijapur Basava Nagar",
        "Description": null,
        "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
        "DeliveryStatus": "Non-Delivery",
        "Circle": "Karnataka",
        "District": "Bijapur(KAR)",
        "Division": "Bijapur",
        "Region": "North Karnataka",
        "Block": "Bijapur",
        "State": "Karnataka",
        "Country": "India",
        "Pincode": "586101"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bijapur Bazar",
        "Description": null,
        "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
        "DeliveryStatus": "Non-Delivery",
        "Circle": "Karnataka",
        "District": "Bijapur(KAR)",
        "Division": "Bijapur",
        "Region": "North Karnataka",
        "Block": "Bijapur",
        "State": "Karnataka",
        "Country": "India",
        "Pincode": "586101"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bijapur Jorapur Peth",
        "Description": null,
        "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
        "DeliveryStatus": "Non-Delivery",
        "Circle": "Karnataka",
        "District": "Bijapur(KAR)",
        "Division": "Bijapur",
        "Region": "North Karnataka",
        "Block": "Bijapur",
        "State": "Karnataka",
        "Country": "India",
        "Pincode": "586101"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bijapur Kutchery",
        "Description": null,
        "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
        "DeliveryStatus": "Non-Delivery",
        "Circle": "Karnataka",
        "District": "Bijapur(KAR)",
        "Division": "Bijapur",
        "Region": "North Karnataka",
        "Block": "Bijapur",
        "State": "Karnataka",
        "Country": "India",
        "Pincode": "586101"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bijapur Market Yard",
        "Description": null,
        "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
        "DeliveryStatus": "Non-Delivery",
        "Circle": "Karnataka",
        "District": "Bijapur(KAR)",
        "Division": "Bijapur",
        "Region": "North Karnataka",
        "Block": "Bijapur",
        "State": "Karnataka",
        "Country": "India",
        "Pincode": "586101"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bijapur Tajbavadi",
        "Description": null,
        "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
        "DeliveryStatus": "Non-Delivery",
        "Circle": "Karnataka",
        "District": "Bijapur(KAR)",
        "Division": "Bijapur",
        "Region": "North Karnataka",
        "Block": "Bijapur",
        "State": "Karnataka",
        "Country": "India",
        "Pincode": "586101"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: ya i just wanted to fetch that data into my website and how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, but there are plenty of tutorials out there. Stackoverflow is meant for helping people with some challenge. Learning the basics and debugging common errors is your chore.